# jquery plugin shwing $.pluginName is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I am writing a code to add a HTML element as a jQuery plugin. Check my code below:

```
$.dw_inactive = function( options ){    
    var settings = $.extend({
                backgroundColor: "#000",
                interval: 1000,
                startTime: 1000,
            }, options );

        var dw_inactive_counter = 0;
        setTimeout("dw_inactive_check", settings.startTime);

        $.fn.dw_inactive_check = function(settings){
            if(!$("body").has("div."+settings.className))
            {
                $("body").add("div").attr("class",settings.className).css({"background-color":settings.backgroundColor});
            }
            setInterval("dw_inactive_check", settings.interval);    
        }
    }
    $.dw_inactive({backgroundColor:"#fff"});
```

It is not working, showing `$.dw_inactive` is not defined. What is the wrong with that code? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
function($){
    $.dw_inactive = function( options ){    
        var settings = $.extend({
                backgroundColor: "#000",
                interval: 1000,
                startTime: 1000,
            }, options );

        var dw_inactive_counter = 0;
        setTimeout("dw_inactive_check", settings.startTime);

        $.fn.dw_inactive_check = function(settings){
            if(!$("body").has("div."+settings.className))
            {
                $("body").add("div").attr("class",settings.className).css({"background-color":settings.backgroundColor});
            }
            setInterval("dw_inactive_check", settings.interval);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to write it as a jQuery plugin

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have declare is:

```
$.fn.dw_inactive_check = function(settings){
```

and what you should declare is:

```
$.fn.dw_inactive = function(settings){
```

if you want to use it like this:

```
$.dw_inactive({backgroundColor:"#fff"});
```

That's why it says it's undefined, as it's not the same name

Comment: So what is the solution? I need to write this function and call the dw_inactive_check function after several intervals. What is the best way to do that?